# Updating menu and tab menus item height in Firefox 89 (Styling the New Proton UI)

Tags: firefox

I'm trying to reestablish the menu and tab menus items height in Firefox 89 (Styling the New Proton UI), as indicated in:

https://www.userchrome.org/firefox-89-styling-proton-ui.html#menuspacing

by editing the file `./chrome/userChrome.css` with:

```css
menupopup > menuitem, menupopup > menu {
  padding-block: 4px !important;
}
:root {
  --arrowpanel-menuitem-padding: 4px 8px !important;
}
```

Where the `./chrome/userChrome.css` is in the folder `about:support` / `Profile Folder`.

But this does not work (I still have the 8px top/bottom padding). Why not? What is the proper way to do so?

Comment: For users who just want a quick-fix to the tab height problem, [steps A-C at the bottom](https://www.userchrome.org/firefox-89-styling-proton-ui.html#tabstyler) of the post linked in the question allow to effectively solve most of the problem just with a few clicks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The utilisation of `userChrome.css` must be activated so firefox looks for it at startup.

For that in `about:config` the option `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` must be set to true.