# Profile folder is broken with firefox v92.0

Tags: firefox

I want to customize Firefox's toolbar style like [how it is done here](https://superuser.com/questions/1653067/updating-menu-and-tab-menus-item-height-in-firefox-89-styling-the-new-proton-ui). But it seems I can't anymore.

According to Firefox:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings

These items and settings will be removed:

```
Extensions and themes
Website permissions
Modified preferences
Added search engines
DOM storage
Security certificate and device settings
Download actions
Toolbar customizations
User styles (chrome subfolder containing userChrome and/or userContent CSS files, if previously created.)
```

In that case, how can I customize my `User styles` for toolbar style in particular ?

Comment: "If you're having problems with Firefox, refreshing may help by restoring the browser to its default state while saving your essential information, like bookmarks and passwords. " - refresh is for when you are having problems. You can save your user styles somewhere and add them back afterwards.

Comment: @DavidPostill How refreshing will bring back a deprecated feature ?

Comment: Use tamper monkey or violent monkey instead

Comment: @DavidPostill How this will help me customize the toolbar style ?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to clarify what your actual problem is and what you are trying to do.